# different directory for tex, pdf and aux files

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files, directory

I am using texstudio, miketex and windows 7. I would like to specify different default directory for all but `.tex` and `.pdf` files so that I could keep working directory clean. But I donot want to use following command everytime

```
latex -output-directory=C:\texoutput -aux-directory=C:\tobedeleted foo.tex
```

I mean, I expect it to be default behaviour. Whenever I compile `abc.tex` or `xyz.tex`, all non `.tex` file should go to directory to be deleted. Is it possible to configure the system this way?

Comment: Can't you write a script that does this?  Must be pretty easy on Windows (but I don't know Windows).

Comment: Which editor you are using? If it is winedt, it can do it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `-output-directory=C:\texoutput -aux-directory=C:\tobedeleted` just before `%.tex` in the lines that configure the compilers in The `Options> Configure TeX Studio > Compiling` menu & submenu as in the first line of this snapshot:

[image]

Comment: How can synctex file also be moved to that directory?

Comment: @Vaibhav: Normally, it should be in that directory. But in that case, forward and inverse search don't work any more – at least in my configuration (MiKTeX + WinEdt).